# Why is an explicit cast required for List<? super myclass>?

Tags: java, super

My code is:

```
List<? super myclass> test_list = new ArrayList<Object>();
   ....
  myclass m;
  m = test_list.get(i);
```

and get the compile error

```
MixedLists.java:43: error: incompatible types
            m=test_list.get(i);
                   ^
  required: myclass
  found:    CAP#1
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object super: myclass from capture of ? super myclass
1 error
```

Comment: I think you want `List<? extends myclass> test_list`

Comment: @Taylor: thank you for a sec i thought, it's a new thing :P

Answer (score 0):

In short, Object is not a myclass: myclass extends Object, i.o.w., Object is a superclass of myclass.

If you had

```
List<? extends myclass> test_list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

You'd have a compile failure. If you had

```
List<Object> test_list = new ArrayList<myclass>();
```

It would compile, but you'd need the explicit cast. What you had is (if you squint) like:

```
List<Object> test_list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Because   `List<Object>` is (probably) more general than `List<? super myclass>` (it may be the essentially the same, if myclass doesn't extend any other class).

This would work just fine:

```
List<? extends myclass> test_list = new ArrayList<myclass>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've explicitly declared the list to be of some type which is a *supertype* of `myclass`:

```
List<? super myclass> test_list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Given that the list may contain items of a type which is a supertype of `myclass`, you can't assign these items to a variable of type `myclass`. Perhaps, as the comment by Taylor suggests, you really wanted to use 'extends':

```
List<? extends myclass> test_list = new ArrayList<myclass>();
```